# Flutter BottomNavigation Issue

Tags: dart, flutter

Material Design doesn't recommend sub-pages in the hierarchy to access the Bottom navigation bar. Hence, there's no clear way of implementing the same bottom navigator in all the screens uniformly. the issue is that once i move to sub pages, the same bottom navigator should be applicable to all

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with

> sub-pages in the hierarchy to access the Bottom navigation bar

But if you are trying to use the same `BottomNavigationBar` for multiple pages, try this:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Example(),
  ));
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ExampleState createState() => new ExampleState();
}



class ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int currentTab = 0; // Index of currently opened tab.
  PageOne pageOne = new PageOne(); // Page that corresponds with the first tab.
  PageTwo pageTwo = new PageTwo(); // Page that corresponds with the second tab.
  PageThree pageThree = new PageThree(); // Page that corresponds with the third tab.
  List<Widget> pages; // List of all pages that can be opened from our BottomNavigationBar.

                      // Index 0 represents the page for the 0th tab, index 1 represents the page for the 1st tab etc...

  Widget currentPage; // Page that is open at the moment.

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pages = [pageOne, pageTwo, pageThree]; // Populate our pages list.
    currentPage = pageOne; // Setting the first page that we'd like to show our user.

                           // Notice that pageOne is the 0th item in the pages list. This corresponds with our initial currentTab value.

                           // These two should match at the start of our application.
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Here we create our BottomNavigationBar.
    final BottomNavigationBar navBar = new BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: currentTab, // Our currentIndex will be the currentTab value. So we need to update this whenever we tab on a new page!
      onTap: (int numTab) { // numTab will be the index of the tab that is pressed.
        setState(() { // Setting the state so we can show our new page.
          print("Current tab: " + numTab.toString()); // Printing for debugging reasons.
          currentTab = numTab; // Updating our currentTab with the tab that is pressed [See 43].
          currentPage = pages[numTab]; // Updating the page that we'd like to show to the user.
        });
      },
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[ // Visuals, see docs for more information: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html
        new BottomNavigationBarItem( //numTab 0
          icon: new Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          title: new Text("Ac unit")
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem( //numTab 1
          icon: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
          title: new Text("Access alarm")
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem( //numTab 2
          icon: new Icon(Icons.access_alarms),
          title: new Text("Access alarms")
        )
      ],

    );

    return new Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: navBar, // Assigning our navBar to the Scaffold's bottomNavigationBar property.
      body: currentPage, // The body will be the currentPage. Which we update when a tab is pressed.
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget { // Creating a simple example page.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(child: new Text("Page one"));
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget { // Creating a simple example page.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(child: new Text("Page two"));
  }
}

class PageThree extends StatelessWidget { // Creating a simple example page.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(child: new Text("Page three"));
  }
}
```

Please elaborate if this is not the wanted effect.

Comment: Thanks you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @Pushkarkumar Could you please mark this answer as the solution if you are satisfied with it? 

Comment: how do you keep the bottom bar if one of the pages has a sub page? for example let say page page 1 has a link to page 5